# Change menu item class by page not click

Tags: css, nav

What is the simplest method to automatically apply a CSS class to the currently selected menu item  of a page in CMS like Joomla or any CMS?

Here on the StackOverflow website as I click through the side menu I can see the class 'youarehere'  is aplied to the current li tag, how is this done?

Even if I arrive at the page via URL (not nav click) the youarehere is active.

As this is a very common thing I thought it would be easy to find but I been searching for hours.

Thanks

Comment: As a developer of a website you should be able to know which is the currently selected menu item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add active class to menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857673/add-active-class-to-menu-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here in this stackoverflow post - [Add active class to menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857673/add-active-class-to-menu-item) this works in Boostrap

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var links = $('.navbar ul li a');
    $.each(links, function (key, va) {
        if (va.href == document.URL) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for those that responded here, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to achieve this, the easiest (but ugliest) way to do it is to add a class to the body of each page, and then use that to change the css of navigation item of choice.

```
const body = document.querySelect('body');
body.classList.add('pageExample');

.pageExample .nav-item-example {color: red;}
```

Comment: Hi @Fredrik Nathorst but how is this done on CMS like Joomla for example when the same nav template and body tag is used for all pages?

Comment: Is Joomla not like Wordpress where each generated page whether it be from the same template or not has a unique class/page -ID?