# Navbar active flag not being set by javascript, everything looks good when set manually

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the boilerplate _Layout page and only changed it to change the names and locations of the nav bar. I have been using basic bootstrap. I am confused on why the nav bar is not setting the active class to show which page I am currently on.

Here is the header HTML from _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">OmniPark Administration Tool</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Core" asp-controller="Organizations" asp-action="Index">Organizations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Core" asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="Index">Devices</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-area="C2P" asp-controller="Payments" asp-action="Index">C2P Payments</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the CSS that it came with, but the rest is the bootstrap css.

```
a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}
```

Then I have tried many variations of the javascript (jQuery?) to get the class to be set to active. This is the root of the problem. When I debug this I can set the active class manually on my links and they look good. I try to put breakpoints in, but it hits the top statement and skips over the rest (including the part where it sets the class to active).

```
<script>
    $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function () {
        $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that we need to set the `active` class on the `nav-item` li item instead of clicked `nav-link` link like:

```
$('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function() {
  $('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

You can also verify this from the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/):

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

you can see in the demos shown there that `active` is set on `li` instead of the `nav-link` itself

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. What you say makes sense. However, when I debug it is completely skipping over the part where it removes active and then sets active. Those lines aren't even getting hit. Any ideas?

Comment: What MIGHT be happening, though, is that it gets set to active and then something comes along and unsets it? I am not sure, because I do not ever see it hit the breakpoints to set it to active. I am breaking apart my code to see if I can get an idea of what is happening and when. I can kinda see the link change color and stay that way while the spinner is going on the browser, then when the page loads it the color changes back.

Comment: Yes. It IS being set! Then for some unknown reason something is unsettling it!

Comment: I don't even have any code that sets messes with the navbar header except for this bit we are working with here.

Comment: Something in here is wiping it out: /*! jQuery v3.3.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */

Comment: Yes. the page is loading again after active is set and wiping it out

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your help. I basically changed to using this solution here because it works and I am able to also add dropdowns into the menu which is perfect for my future plans on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857673/add-active-class-to-menu-item

Answer (score 1):

I basically changed to using this solution here because it works and I am able to also add dropdowns into the menu which is perfect for my future plans on this site.

I was stuck on using TagHelpers in my head and it was holding me back. This is a much better solution to my problem.

[Add active class to menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857673/add-active-class-to-menu-item)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong CSS selector. `.nav-link` is inside `.nav-item`. So use the CSS selector `.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link` in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried this before and it did not make a difference, but it looks like the other person's answer explains that I was setting the active in the wrong spot. However, when I debug it is completely skipping over the part where it removes active and then sets active. Those lines aren't even getting hit. Any ideas?

Comment: It IS being set it turns out, then something is coming along and unsetting it. Gah! I don't even have any code that sets messes with the navbar header except for this bit we are working with here.

Comment: Yes. the page is loading again after active is set and wiping it out

Comment: The fact that page is loading again after clicking is worthy for us. That's why active is being unset. What you need to do is in ready method unset the active class as you are unsetting now. Then iterate through all the li and check which li has the a tag which points to current page and set that li active. I have done this previously so many times and it works fine.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your help. I think the solution I found does basically what you are saying. I basically changed to using this solution here because it works and I am able to also add dropdowns into the menu which is perfect for my future plans on this site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857673/add-active-class-to-menu-item